# How to tell a search button to inherit search fields height?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML:

```
    <form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" class="google">
    <input type="hidden" name="as_q" value="site:hyoutube.com/" />
    <p><label for="keyword">Search</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="keyword" name="q" value="" class="sfield" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Search" class="sbutton" /></p>
</form>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.google{
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .sfield{
      height: 24px;
    }
    .sbutton{
      height: inherit;
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xeo649cu/2/)

As you can see, the search field is of different height to the search button. How can I make them the same height without using absolute values like "14px"?

I tried to look it up, but I was unable to find a straight-forward solution. How should I go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: `inherit` as word says it works when there is a `parent` and `child` relationship. in your case it is independent controls.

Answer (score 0):

Only add "display: flex;" on the parent element and then add 100% height on button like this

```
.google{
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
}
.sbutton{
   height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2tkmj9qb/2/)